# Why wont my data save to xls?

Tags: python, python-2.7, scrapy, xls, xlwt

I have written a pretty simple web scraper using scrapy. I would like to save the scraped data to an .xls file, as I have an existing module to read an xls and sort the scraped data. But I've hit what feels like a silly stumbling block, actually saving the .xls.

- The spider itself works (it crawls and scrapes the required data)
- The .xls is being created and initialised correctly.
- The scraped data is written to the xls after scraping each item.

However, where ever I put the save statement, it seems to get saved **before** the actual web scraping begins. Leaving me with an initialised (first row filled out with titles) but otherwise empty spreadsheet. Here is what I have (website removed to save innocent server)

```
# encoding=utf-8
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector 
from scrapy.item import Item, Field
from xlwt import Workbook

# Working row on new spreadsheet
row_number = 0

# Create new spreadsheet
newDb = Workbook(encoding='utf-8')
newFile = newDb.add_sheet('Sheet1')
values = ['product','description','image']

class TestSpider(CrawlSpider):
    # Initiate new spreadsheet
    global newFile
    global values
    global row_number
    for cell in range (len(values)):
        newFile.write(row_number, cell, values[cell])
    row_number = row_number + 1

    # Initiate Spider
    name = "Test"
    allowed_domains = []
    start_urls = ["http://www.website.to/scrape",]
    rules = (Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths="//div[@class='content']/h3"), callback='parse_product'),)

    def parse_product(self, response):
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        item = TestItem()
        item['product'] = hxs.select('//div [@class = "col-right"][1]/table/tr[1]/td/text()').extract()
        item['description'] = hxs.select('//div[@class="columns"][1]/div [@class = "col-right"]/p/text()' ).extract()
        item['image'] = hxs.select('//img /@src').extract()

        global values
        global newFile
        global row_number

        # This is where products are written to the xls
        for title in values:
            # test to increase row_number, at the start of each new product
            if title == "product":
                row_number = row_number + 1
            try:
                newFile.write(row_number, values.index(title), item[title] )
            except:
                newFile.write(row_number, values.index(title), '')

class TestItem(Item):
    product = Field()
    description = Field()
    image = Field()
```

I believe I'm correct in saying just need to add
`global newDb

newDb.save('./products_out.xls')`

In the correct place, but again, it seems no matter where I add this, print statements indicate the order of operations is always: 
create xls -> initialise xls -> save xls -> scrape and write to xls -> close without saving.

I'm pretty new to development, and I'm at a loss on this, any advice would be gratefully received.

Comment: Are you sure you're getting data?

Comment: Yes, (when pointed at the correct start_url), adding `return item` to the end of parse_product prints out collected data to the terminal as it scrapes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally you should create a custom item pipeline class (have a look at the scrapy documentation for examples) and put all your file writing code in there.